# ngTable is not working in Module

Tags: angularjs, module, ngtable

ngTable is not working after adding 'ngTable' as a parameter in module.

Below is my module which was working fine without 'ngTable'

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngMessages']);
```

Installed ngTable library in a soltuing. Below is my module after adding 'ngTable' as parameter

**`var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router', 'ngMessages','ngTable']);`**

**Error:** angular.min.js:38 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463)][1](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%252%E2%80%A6ogleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.4.8%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463))

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the references for ngTable

```
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.ngtable/0.3.2/ng-table.css
http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/angular.ngtable/0.3.2/ng-table.js
```

Working [`Fiddle`](http://fiddle.jshell.net/sajeetharan/nb9yveo8/)

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, Yes i added ng-Table library using Nuget Package manager.

Comment: @ShakeerHussain hi tell me

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, Yes i added ng-Table library using Nuget Package manager.